# Possible bug in traditional form expression enclosed in ""

Tags: formatting, notation

The following:

```
a="FormBox[RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["\:f74d", RowBox[{"\:f74e", " ", "\:03b8"}]], "=", RowBox[{RowBox[{"x", " ", SuperscriptBox["sin", "2"]}], "+", RowBox[{"x", " ", SuperscriptBox["cos", "2"]}]}]}], TraditionalForm]";
Style[a,FontSize->20]
```

displays with a leading " but no trailing ". I would expect the output to be `"expression"` or `expression` but getting `"expression` is obviously a bug. How can I fix this?

As you can see, I am storing a math expression with typesetting that may have a collision with the = assignment operator. What is the preferred method for assigning an expression that contains an unevaluated `=` operator? Is using a string the only way?

using mathematica 12 cloud based IDE.

Comment: What are those special characters at the beginning of your string? Would it work for you to just wrap your expression in Hold?

Comment: the special characters were put there by mathematica after escaping to type exp e. after I posted I found out HoldForm works. This has a new side affect of turning the expression into an atomic that can not be edited after it is converted.

Comment: I get this (Mac, V12.2), which looks fine, I think: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQQri.png

Answer (score 6):

When I copied and pasted your code into a V12.1.1 notebook on my system (MacOS 10.13.4), I got the following:

[image: code_image]

which doesn't display the problem you experienced. So I don't think there is any bug involved, just something corrupted in your notebook. You might try evaluating your expression in a clean notebook to see if that makes the problem go away.

But you also ask for recommendations of better practice. I recommend the following.

```
a = HoldForm[E^(I θ) == Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ]]
```

[image: out.1]

With this definition of `a`, you can still style the held expression.

```
Style[TraditionalForm @ a, 20, "TR"]
```

[image: out.2]

You can also do all kinds of other things with the expression held by `a` by using [`ReleaseHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html). Here are a couple of examples:

```
ReleaseHold[a] // Simplify
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
{x, y} = Cases[ReleaseHold[a], u : (Sin | Cos)[θ] :> u, All]; {x, y}
```

> ```
> {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}
> ```

#### Update

It occured to me that some people might prefer

```
{x, y} = Simplify[ReIm[ReleaseHold[a][[2]]], θ ∈ Reals]
```

to the 2nd example given above; it gives the same result. Of course, this works, too:

```
{x, y} = FullSimplify[ReIm[ReleaseHold[a][[1]]], θ ∈ Reals]
```

After all, equality is equality  (see 1st example above for for confirmation of equality).